# d3 v4 - have value on left side of single horizontal bar chart

Tags: d3.js

below is the code for a horizontal bar chart in its current form. I would like to move the value to the left side of the bar chart. I tried `.attr("text-anchor", "start")` but it didn't work. Any help is appreciated, and hopefully you can provide some comments to help explain some of the principles in formatting labels/values. Thanks!

```
var data = [{        
    "xAxis": "72.1"
    }];
    var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 80
    },
    width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
    var y = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([height, 0])
    .padding(0.4);
    var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain([0, 100]);
    var svg = d3.select(".barChartContainer").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 500)
    .attr("height", 200)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    y.domain(data.map(function(d) {
    return d.yAxis;
    }));
    var backgroundBar = svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "barBackground")
    .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.yAxis);
    })
    .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
    .attr("width", function(d) {
    return x(100);
    });
    var bar = svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.yAxis);
    })
    .attr("width", function(d) {
    return x(d.xAxis);
    });
    var labels = svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("text")        
    var values = svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("text")        
    .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.yAxis) + y.bandwidth() / 2;
    })
    .attr("x", 10)
    .text(function(d) {
    return +d.xAxis
    })
    .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x(d.xAxis) + 10;
    });
```

**Current bar chart**

[image: Current bar chart]

**What I would like**
[image: new bar chart]

Comment: I wrote this code, answering your last question. Simply change the `x` attribute for the texts. This line is the one that moves the texts to the right margin of the bars: `.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.xAxis) + 10;});`. Change that to the value you want (e.g., `-10`).

Comment: @GerardoFurtado do you want to put an answer (like below) so I can give you credit? I am going to have a bunch more questions around customizing this bar chart format.

Comment: Nope, thanks. Feel free to accept your own answer. Just a tip: since the value is the same for any text, you don't need that function. Just do `.attr("x", x(-10))`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the last line:

```
.attr("x", function(d) {
        return x(d.xAxis) + 10;
        });
```

And replace with:

```
.attr("x", x(-10));
```